# Are purchased crates different from obtained ones?

Tags: rocket-league

After the latest update now items stack in the inventory, if they aren't painted or certified.
I've noticed that Spring Fever crates obtained playing online and purchased by flower tokens are considered different items, because they don't stack.

Is there a reason for this? Do their items have different odds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [Psyonix themselves](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/drop-rates-in-rocket-league-crates/) revealed the odds of obtaining a certain item in crates, and the origin of a crate has no effect on them.

The reason they are in different stacks probably is [a bug](https://psyonix.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=42494).

Comment: Totally forgot to accept your answer!